# Closest Facility Arcgis online javascript not returning data

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to use the Closest Facility (CF) function in ArcGIS API for Javascript. I need to be able to pass a shape coming from a feature service as an incident, and use a feature service with multiple points as the facilities.

Currently when I use the Closest Facility task, nothing happens. No calls are made at all if I look at the network activity.

```
CFTask.solve(CFParams).then(function (solveResult) {
    array.forEach(solveResult.routes, function (route, index) {
        console.log(route);
    });

});
```

I understand that i may be passing it incorrect data, but would expect an error message, rather than the nothing I get now.

2 questions:

- Does the above code snippet actually run the Closest Facility
  function?
- How do add data from a feature service to a feature set correctly?

Comment: You've got more chance of getting answers with a more complete code snippet. How did you initialise `CFTask`? How did you initialise `CFParams`?

Comment: Please dont ask 2 questions in the same post. Create 2 different questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, verify if an error is triggered inside the promise when you run the code snippet by using `catch` method:

```
CFTask.solve(CFParams).then(function (solveResult) {
    solveResult.routes.forEach(function(route, index) {
        console.log(route);
    });

}).catch(console.error);
```

If you see an error message printed in the console, add it to your question.

Also there is a syntax error in your `forEach` function